# how to add two controls in template field and make second control in the right aligned in the next align

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have one template field . in that i have two controls text box and label control . i want to align label control in the bottom right of the column in the grid view.
[image]

```
      <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="ITEM CODE / DESCRIPTION">

<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr><td><%#Eval("ItemCodeandDescription")%></td></tr>
        <tr> <td style="text-align:right"><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="VAT @ 5%" runat="server"/></td></tr>
    </table>



</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemCodeandDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>

</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It's difficult to imagine where you want to position your label control as after render it becomes a span tag that too inside a table. Show your current grid as image and where you want to position your label control.

Comment: i have added image kindly see it

Comment: Wrap your label inside a div and add `text-align: right` css to div. If possible set div width: 100%; I'm not css geek but this might help you out :)

Comment: hmm working...  <div align="right">